# Back press is not working in SaleForce login screen

Tags: android, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have created a sample app for saleforce SDK implementation using `forcedroid create` in terminal. It create an app which works perfectly. Only the issue is that I cannot back press when login UI is present. On backpress it reloads the UI again and again. After login I can back press without any issue.

I have only one Activity which extends Saleforce activity. I have not made any code changes, all the codes are added by `forcedroid create` command

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onBackPressed()` method in your login activity

Comment: sale force has its own activity and launched my its own when initiated. don't have much control over it.
Could you be more clear , how we can override its onBackPressed()

Comment: You can create new Activity with extending sale force LoginActivity and override  onBackPressed() method also set the login activity to sales force in Application class as follows SmartSyncSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class,MyLoginActivity.class);